# Why is my Ajax file upload not working - CodeIgnite, JQuery, Apache, localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**EDIT :** How do I get the file path of the portfolio directory, Like this : $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . '/../portfolio/'; ? It seems to work, but is there a cleaner way to do it ?

---

I am trying to upload a zip file via Ajax in CodeIgniter, using JQuery
Here I am presenting only the relevant parts, so as not to make the post too lengthy.

I am getting Error : The upload path does not appear to be valid. Which is coming from Upload handler php file at the following lines

```
$this->data['message'];
echo $this->data['message'];
```

and is printed via javascript at the following line

```
$( "#upload_error div:first-child" ).html ( data ); }
```

View File (codeIgniter views)

```
<form id="sign_up" action="<?php echo site_url ( 'www' ) . '/' . $this->router->fetch_class (  ) ;?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" class="validate" id="user_file" name="userfile">

    <button class="btn-large" style="width: 100%;" type="submit" name="register_user" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Javascript/JQuery

```
var files;

$( document ).ready (   function (  ) {  
    $ ( '#user_file' ).on ( 'change', prepareUpload );
}

function prepareUpload ( event ) { files = event.target.files; }

$( '#submit' ).click ( function ( event ) {

    var data = new FormData (  );
    data.append ( 'userfile', files [ 0 ] );
    data.append ( 'ajaxUpload', 'true' );

    $.ajax ( {

        method : 'POST',
        url : scriptUrl,
        data : data,
        cache : false,
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        dataType : 'html', // we will return simple true or error message from the php file
        success : function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {

            if ( data === 'true' ) { 
                $ ( '#upload_success').html ( 'success' ); }
             else {
                $( "#upload_error div:first-child" ).html ( data ); }
        },
        error : function ( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ) {
            alert ( 'xhr status : ' + xhr.status);
            alert ( 'thrownError : ' + thrownError);   
            alert ( 'xhr message : ' + xhr.message );
        }

    } );

}
```

Upload Handler file (php)

```
public function do_upload (  ) {
     $this->load->library ( 'upload' );
      if (  ! $this->upload->do_upload (   )  ) {
        $this->data['message'];
        echo $this->data['message'];
    }

    else {
        echo 'true';
    }

}
```

Finally upload.php config file

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'http://localhost/mysite/portfolio';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['max_size'] = '2048KB'; // 2mb
```

And this is the directory structure

```
mysite
-lib
--application
---controller
---config
---model
---views
--system
-portfolio
-www
--index.php
```

Comment: The `$config['upload_path']` needs to be a file path , not a URL. Try using `FCPATH`

Comment: @CodeGodie But how can I get file path to the mysite -- portfolio, which resides outside the public_html/www  ?

Comment: Try this `$config['upload_path'] = './portfolio';`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam That doesn't work